# minimum number of length k

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures

> You are given a positive integer n. The beauty factor of a number is the sum of digits obtained till the obtained sum is a single digit.
>
> Example
>
> Beauty factor of 1987 = 1+9+8+7 = 25 = 2+5 = 7
> Beauty factor of 10 = 1+0 = 1
> You are given a beauty factor b, . Your task is to find a minimum number (n) of length k whose beauty factor is b .
>
> Here, the length of a number is defined as the number of digits a number has.
>
> Note: The digits of the number in the output must be distinct and must be a positive integer
>
> for example with b=5 and k=3 .answer is 149.

can anyone help me with this puzzle?

Comment: What have you tried? Stack Overflow is not a homework site. Show us a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), and explain what you are having trouble with.

Comment: i am telling my approach. suppose b is given as 5 and k is given as 3. Now i break this b in 1 and 4 .so my new number is 14.Now i have to make that number whose sum is obtained as 14. So i have to add 9. So my newly formed number is 149. So this is my least possible number (n).

Comment: Just tell me the initial approach for this question.

Comment: What about 104?

Comment: @VSSChaitanyaChavali digits must be positive

Comment: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)

Comment: You should detail your approach in the post, not in a comment, and explain what problem you have with it. Moreover, if you have an algorithm but no code, better to use [algorithm] tag only, not [C++].

Answer (score 1):

Recursive sum of digits of any number = `N % 9 (9*n + remainder)`, except for multiples of 9 where it will be 0 and the number 0. For 0 you can trivially handle.

Backtrack to select `k` digits out of [1-9] digits in increasing order, check if the `k` digit number formed by sorted sequence of selected digits `n` has beauty score `b`, i.e whether `n % 9` == `b % 9`. If there is a match terminate.

Comment: sir,can u please show your code?

Comment: But sir we are given only b and k in the question. How to find n?

Comment: no sir . i have not done that. Can u show me ur code?

Comment: n is not given in the question sir. What to take for n? only b and k is given.

Comment: This answer is good because it explains the similarity and the difference between "beauty number of N" and `N % 9`. But suggesting binary search sounds very odd to me. We're looking for the minimum `N` of length `k` whose beauty number is `b`. The minimum number of length `k` is `10^(k-1)`. The beauty number of that number is extremely easy to calculate. Then finding the next number whose beauty number is `b` is not hard...

Comment: Binary search converges fast... To what? The problem asks for **the smallest** number N of length k whose beauty number is b. You don't need to search all numbers of length k. There is a simle answer to this problem, much simpler than binary search, and I don't even see how binary search would solve the problem. How would binary search find the smallest number? Also, how would binary search even find a number at all? Binary search is an algorithm to apply to a sorted array. But numbers are not naturally sorted by beauty number.

Comment: @รยקคгรђשค b=8 k=8: N=10000007 without a doubt.

Comment: Oh. I missed that requirement. The question literally contains the sentence "Your task is to find a minimum number (n) of length k whose beauty factor is b .", though. Well, in that case, I need to think about it a little.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224245/discussion-between-stef-and-).

Comment: The modulo approach is clearly the good one. But why using backtracking ? Easy to determine the sum of the digits, and then a simple filling procedure, starting from 123...k

Comment: @Damien I tried but couldn't find a better way to utilize the modulo property. Take for example k=3 and beauty 5, here answer will be 149 and not 122 or 131. Task is to find first N with beauty b, length k and unique digits. We need to backtrack to search for a big value than current value if current value doesn't work out.

Comment: In the example (b = 5, k = 3), the sum of the digits is equal to `b + 9*x`. The sum of digits is at least equal to `k(k+1)/2` (6 for k=3, corresponding to `n=123`). Then, the *best* sum of digits is equal to the minimum number greater than this minimum. Here, it is equal to `9+5=14`. Then, starting from `123`, we have to increase the digits, starting from the LSB, until we get 14. In the first round, we get `129`, for a sum equal to 12. In the second round, we have to add 2 (14-12) to the second LSB, and we get `149`.

Comment: @Damien Actually backtracking shouldn't be bad as it is (9 choose k), or even the total search space of required numbers would be 2^9.